# How can I create an idle layout where no any button can wake it up?

Tags: android

I am developing a security apps and I would like to create an idle layout.
When someone tried to login to gain access to the phone, the system only allows 3 attempts, after 3 failed attempts, an idle layout will activated for 15min, no any key or button can wake it up until the timer expired. I have tried to set the timer and it succeeds but I do not know how to make sure it become idle with no any button can disturb it... thanks

Comment: How about the phone buttons, I mean not the buttons in the apps layout...

Answer (score 0):

After three attempt, set button disable trough `Button.setEnabled()`  and start a `Timer`. Into the `TimerTask` runnable, set the enabled state to `true`.

see [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html), [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), [setEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)